# Size a div based on non-visible ghost content

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How is it possible to **size a `<div>` not based on the real content, but based on a non-displayed ghost content?**

Example: here the box with content "A" should be sized as if its content was "BCD":

```css
.container { display: flex; width: 10em; }
.item { flex-grow: 1; text-align: center; padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
border: solid black 1px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item" data-ghost-content="BCD">A</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

Note: the container is a flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how your page is created, manually or with JS. But if you can manage to add an inline style with a `--char-count` custom property you can use the `flex` shorthand to get a generic solution:

```css
.item { flex: var(--char-count, 1) } /* or defaults to: 1 1 0% */
```

Do not use `flex-grow` as for this solution `flex-basis` actually needs to be `0%`

The fun part of flexbox is that, when using different `flex-grow` values (as `flex`), the mechanism will distribute the available space to ratio using the various defined `flex-grow` values.

BTW: In CSS var(.., fallback) the *fallback* value can also be `0` if so required, resulting in flexbox default `flex-grow: 0` for 'unset' items.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 10em;
}
.item {
    flex: var(--char-count, 1); /* fallback 1 if 'unset' */
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-ghost-content="BCD" style="--char-count: 3">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless the font is monospaced, this will work incorrectly if the ghost content is `iii` and the actual content `M` (approximately the same width).

Comment: @Basj Here's a [Codepen: Flexbox N-grid](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/gOvWZwq) I did last year extensively testing this flexbox behavior...

Comment: @InSync surely true, but it depends on whether OP wants it three times as wide, or needs the width to be the exact physical width of the characters. I make no assumptions on that, just showing an alternative solution. My first thought was actually using JS `element.textMetrics` or `canvas.measureText` (...with all the hassle attached...).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make the additional content `visibility: hidden;` and it will consume space but not be shown:

```css
.container { display: flex; width: 10em; }
.item { flex-grow: 1; text-align: center; padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
border: solid black 1px; }
[data-ghost-content]:after {
  content: attr(data-ghost-content);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item" data-ghost-content=BC>A</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

In this approach, the "ghost content" would not include the actual visible content that's already there in the element, so it's just "BC".

If you want the result to be centered, you could have "ghost" data attributes for ":before" and ":after".

Comment: This wouldn't work if the actual content is not a prefix of the ghost content.

Comment: @InSync that is true. Honestly if it were my markup I'd add a class to impose a `min-width` or something.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your answer! In fact in my application, the actual content is not a prefix of the ghost content (I modified my question). Do you see a general solution?

Comment: @Basj why not impose a width via CSS directly, instead of by implication with content? Can you describe the motivation for this?

Comment: @Pointy I have lots of div, for which the size should be done in the HTML, not in the CSS. Imagine you create a on-screen touch-keyboard with dozens of "keys".

Comment: PS: yes, the real content should be centered in each item div

Comment: Well that still seems odd; consider what would happen if the "key" labels were internationalized and shown in a different locale.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can adjust your structure a bit?

```css
.container { display: flex; width: 10em; }
.item { flex-grow: 1; text-align: center; padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
border: solid black 1px; }
.ghost {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-content ghost">ABC</div>
  <div class="item-content">A</div>
</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `.wrapper`, like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-ghost-content="BCD">
    <div class="wrapper">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...and then, a hidden pseudo-element containing the ghost content. The actual content will be `absolute`-ly positioned so as not to consume any space:

```css
[data-ghost-content]::before {
  content: attr(data-ghost-content);
  visibility: hidden;
}

[data-ghost-content] > .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}
```

To preserve `text-align`ing, make `.item` flexboxes:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

[data-ghost-content]::before {
  content: attr(data-ghost-content);
  visibility: hidden;
}

[data-ghost-content] > .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}


/* Demo only */

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 10em;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-ghost-content="BCD">
    <div class="wrapper">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you're able to adjust the HTML, to include a `<span>` tag for the visible content, then I'd suggest using CSS grid, as this allows elements to be stacked "on top of" each other, in the space from background to foreground, as follows (with explanatory comments in the code):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 10em;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

/* setting up CSS grid on .item elements with the
   data-ghost-content attribute: */
.item[data-ghost-content] {
  display: grid;
  /* placing items to the start (on the block-axis, vertical
     in English) and to the center (on the inline-axis,
     horizontal in English); this is in the event of a longer
     "data-ghost-content" attribute being set so the visible
     content is placed similarly to the neighbouring
     elements/content: */
  place-items: start center;
}

.item[data-ghost-content] > span {
  /* placing the <span> in the first column and first row: */
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

/* using the ::before pseudo-element to display the
   attribute-value of the data-ghost-content attribute: */
.item[data-ghost-content]::before {
  content: attr(data-ghost-content);
  /* placing the pseudo-element in the first row and column
     of the grid, similarly to the <span> element: */
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  user-select: none;
  /* hiding the element by setting its visibility to hidden,
     which allows it to retain its space in the document: */
  visibility: hidden;
  /* positioning the pseudo-element behind the <span>: */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-ghost-content="BCD">
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>B</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1mfdyt96/).

References:

- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select/).
- [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).
- [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).